# how to create custom attribute for order using data-patch in magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.4, custom-attributes, data-patch

how can we create custom order attribute programatically using data-patch in magento 2.4.6 ? I know how to create this customer attribute for order using install schema but currently I am using magento 2.4.6 version so as per standards I wanted to create the same by using data-patch. Can you suggest how to achieve the same by using data-patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a patch for that, you can simply use db_schema.xml for that. There you can define new columns in the sales_order table (and/or in the sales_order_grid table, to use it in your order grid). You may also want to create that attribute in your quote.
Here is an example of the
`Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="quote" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="your_custom_attribute" nullable="true" length="40" comment="Your custom attribute"/>
    </table>
    <table name="sales_order" resource="default" engine="innodb">        
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="your_custom_attribute" nullable="true" length="40" comment="Your custom attribute"/>
    </table>
    <table name="sales_order_grid" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="your_custom_attribute" nullable="true" length="40" comment="Your custom attribute"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

If you want to show that attribute in your order grid, you also have to add a virtual type to your
`Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="joins" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_custom_attribute" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="table" xsi:type="string">sales_order</item>
                    <item name="origin_column" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="target_column" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_custom_attribute" xsi:type="string">sales_order.your_custom_attribute</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

and add an ui component to show your new column in the order grid `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <columns name="sales_order_columns">
            <column name="your_custom_attribute">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item
                            name="label"
                            xsi:type="string"
                            translate="true">
                            Your custom attribute
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```